# Best approach to send data from one django app to another

Tags: django, messaging

When Django App A completes an action I want it to add some data to Django App B.  They are currently on different domains but the same server.

Option 1.

I've tried doing POST requests both with jQuery and using [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) but in both instances the POST is converted to a GET.  Suspect this a cross-domain issue and have applied the cross-domain middleware and the various changes to the headers suggested but still not cracked it.
Is this the best approach to pursue?

Option 2

I could set up a shared database so A writes to it and B reviews it and picks up the data.  This seems very clunky.

Option 3

Some sort of messaging/queueing system.  Redis?  Celery?  From a read of the documentation it is not immediately obvious to me how I implement the setup I need.

Option X
Another approach?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**  Try a webservice API framework for Django like [TastyPie](http://tastypieapi.org/). JSON was designed for data interchange, it allows completely different systems to talk.

**Option 2:** Don't duplicate data. There is nothing wrong with both apps accessing the same database, infact this makes perfect sense.

**Option 3** Option 3 makes little sense for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Am using tastypie and the tests all work but unable to post data across.  This approach also has the weakness that if the there is an error the transaction is lost, so I need to create some record on the sending side to reconcile with the receiving side anyway.

Comment: I need to keep separate database as the two apps are completely different.